# Transaction behaviour in simultaneous call

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ado.net

I have created a Web API service method, this will creates a transaction and insert/update records into database table(SQL Server), if more than one web jobs calling this service method simultaneously, is there any chance to get deadlock or will insert/update properly in same tables without any loss/block?

Consider am not using distributed transaction here, when ever the job calling API method, this will create new transaction.

Comment: If you are inserting/updating different rows and have appropriate primary key constraints and indexes, blocking and deadlocks are unlikely. Short-term blocking will occur when multiple sessions attempt to update the same row.

Comment: Thanks for response,  am inserting/updating different rows only.

Comment: You ought to be good then as long as you perform due diligence to ensure only the rows needed by the queries are touched. Examine the query execution plans proactively examine to verify indexes are used as expected.